# What is the purpose of the _meta_MSMP files in WSO2 Micro Integrator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-integrator

Does anyone know the purpose of the _meta_MSMP* files in the task directory which is similar to the one shown below?

`_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.tasks/definitions/-1234/ESB_TASK/`

The state of the message processors retains the settings in the _meta_MSMP files after a restart when files are individually deployed on a server.

Note: these files are not deployed in a CAR.

Answer (score 0):

Once you deploy any NTask related integrations (Scheduled Tasks, Message Processors) all the Metadata and the state of the task will be written to this file. This will be used when changing the state, retrieving tasks, etc.

Upon quick investigation of the source, [TaskInfo](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/01c6b5ce5a7d88bab5f4e7eb4a6f8597a80bddd0/components/mediation/tasks/org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/micro/integrator/ntask/core/TaskInfo.java) seems to be the Class that holds this `_meta_MASMP` file. As an example, if you deactivate/activate a Task, this information will be persisted in this file. On state change [TaskRepository.setTaskMetadataProp()](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/01c6b5ce5a7d88bab5f4e7eb4a6f8597a80bddd0/components/mediation/tasks/org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/micro/integrator/ntask/core/TaskUtils.java#L108) will be called, which will eventually call [FileBasedTaskRepository.setTaskMetadataProp()](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/01c6b5ce5a7d88bab5f4e7eb4a6f8597a80bddd0/components/mediation/tasks/org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/micro/integrator/ntask/core/impl/FileBasedTaskRepository.java#L285) which will write to `_meta_*` file [here](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/01c6b5ce5a7d88bab5f4e7eb4a6f8597a80bddd0/components/mediation/tasks/org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/micro/integrator/ntask/core/impl/FileBasedTaskRepository.java#L302).